# sql group AND condition

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select Product options using AND statements?
[image]

I need to select all product options, comparing two columns, but I do something wrong...

```
SELECT * FROM `cart_option` 
WHERE (`cart_option`.`product_id`=100) 
AND ((`option_id`=2 AND `option_value_id`=3)) AND ((`option_id`=1 AND `option_value_id`=2))
```

How should I group the AND statements ?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL-Server?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: Your logic doesn't make sense, because a cart_option can never have `option_id = 2` and `option_id = 1` at the same time

Comment: what's the expected result?

Comment: You probably need `OR` and `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2`. But that is not clear from your question.

Comment: I want to know does product have, (option_id=2 and option_value_id=3) and (option_id=1 and option_value_id=2) i.e two option with values

Comment: You will always get an empty resultset for that, because as I wrote a cart_option can't have the value `option_id = 2` and the value `option_id = 1` at the same time and that is what your query says... (no matter how many braces you use ;-) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're confusing `AND` with `OR`...

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cart_option
WHERE 
    cart_option.product_id=100
AND (
        (option_id=2 AND option_value_id=3)
        OR
        (option_id=1 AND option_value_id=2)
)
```

Comment: No, i need to use AND with AND (as i understand)

Comment: As @schlonzo wrote, it doesn't make any sense. The WHERE clause specifies a criteria for a row column, and a single row column of "option_id" (for example) can't be both "1" and "2". I'd recommend you to read about combining "AND" and "OR" statements in MySQL here: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and_or.php

Comment: @john, getting first AND second row doesn't mean that you have to use 'AND' in their respective queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can't with AND only, option_id cannot be equal to 2 and equal to 1 at the same time.
This should do the trick

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cart_option
WHERE
    cart_option.product_id = 100
AND ((option_id = 2 AND option_value_id = 3) OR
     (option_id = 1 AND option_value_id = 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this?

```
SELECT * FROM cart_option`
WHERE (cart_option.product_id=100) 
OR ((option_id=2 AND option_value_id=3)) 
OR ((option_id=1 AND option_value_id=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace AND with OR

```
((`option_id`=2 AND `option_value_id`=3) OR (`option_id`=1 AND `option_value_id`=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM cart_option
WHERE cart_option.product_id = 100
  AND (option_id, option_value_id) IN ((2, 3), (1, 2))
```

If both rows exist in the table, the result must be `2`.